# Hiding element in ionic2: Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: cordova, typescript, angular, ionic2

I have a problem with DOM elements in my ionic2 app. When I trying do something like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="el1" tabIcon="list-box"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="el2" tabIcon="git-pull-request"></ion-tab>
  <div *ngIf="'admin'=='admin'">
    <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Admin" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
  </div>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

everything is OK. But when I set angular variable in constructor:

```
export class TabsPage {
  constructor() {
    this.userRole = "admin";
```

and

```
<ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="el1" tabIcon="list-box"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="el2" tabIcon="git-pull-request"></ion-tab>
      <div *ngIf="{{userRole}}=='admin'">
        <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Admin" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
      </div>
      <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

the application returns me an error:

> Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known native property

How I can hide this element when `userRole = 'admin'`?

Comment: Sorry, my question is "How i can hide this element when userRole is different than 'admin' e.g 'user'

Comment: What if you put the `*ngIf="'admin'=='admin'"` attribute directly in the `ion-tab` and not in a wrapping `div`?

Comment: The same effect.  When string == string element is shown when string1 == string2 element is hidden but when variableX = 'string' and variableX == 'string' it returns error

Comment: Try `userRole` without the `{{}}`: `*ngIf="userRole=='admin'"`

Comment: Dude you are genius !!! Thanks it works.

Comment: Great. I'm going to post is as an answer to future readers, ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition expression at `*ngIf="expression"` is already [going to be evaluated](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template), no need to use `{{}}`.

So

```
<div *ngIf="{{userRole}}=='admin'">
```

should really be

```
<div *ngIf="userRole=='admin'">
```