# ionic2: Show secured tab in run time after user signed in

Tags: ionic2

I have an ionic2 app.  Users can sign-in to view secured data. Users can also see the generic views without a need to login.  I separated the secured and non-secured data into different tabs.

Users can sign-in from my about page(view).  My question is: how can I show the secured tab after an user has signed-in?

Here is what I did:
I created a property: loggedIn in my service.ts which is shared by entire app.

In my about page, I changed the loggedIn property to true after users signed-in.  In my tab.html, I have `<ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn==true"`.

But how do I notify my tab component / and tab view that the loggedIn property has been changed by the signed-in process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/)

In your login service provider/component:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

    // first page (publish an event when a user has logged in)
    function login() {
    //...login code
      console.log('User logged in!')
      events.publish('user:login', user);
    }
```

In your page containing tabs,

```
constructor(public events: Events) {}
ngOnInit(){
events.subscribe('user:login', (user) => {
  // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
this.isLoggedin=true;
});
```

Comment: thank you! That works!! One more thing. I tried to write a logout function to hide the tab, if user logged out. I used the same event, but this time I publish loggedIn=false. However, the tab (`<ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn==true"`), doesn't disappear when loggedIn became false. When I login again, the tab kept appending..  I understand this is just an additional issue, but I am thinking to ask here, since they are related. Thank you again for the big help!

Comment: how do you set isLoggedIn false for the same event? you used "user:logout"?

Comment: Hi Suraj: Yes.  I just changed isLoggedIn to false when user logout. And I am using the same "user:login" topic. (should I use different topic?).  I posted my code snippet below, which will be easier to read :-)

Comment: is it printing false when logged out?

Comment: Yes. this.loggedIn printed false when logout.  
[Log] false (console-via-logger.js, line 173)

Comment: try `<ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn"></ion-tab>` or `<ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn=='true'"></ion-tab>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131063/discussion-between-george-huang-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: Thank you very much Suraj.... stackoverflow suggested me to move to chat..       I declared: loggedIn: boolean = false in my tab component. I also tried <ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn"></ion-tab> or `<ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn===true"></ion-tab> and both somehow don't work. I couldn't do <ion-tab *ngIf="loggedIn=='true'">, since loggedIn is boolean (compile error)...  I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543028/hiding-element-in-ionic2-cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-pr . but their situation was a bit different from my case. we are trying to hide the tab in runtime.

Comment: try enabled=loggedIn.. tab is not paet of DOM for ngIf to remove..it is part of navigation ctrl.

Comment: regarding the removing of tab based on login, you could have 2 different tab components with their own set of tabs and do this.navCtrl.setRoot() based on event. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The code in the about component (the login/logout page):

```
    public login(){

        //this.appService.loggedIn = true;
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.events.publish('user:login', true);
        //console.log(this.appService.loggedIn);
    }
    public logout(){

        //this.appService.loggedIn = false;
        this.loggedIn = false;
        this.events.publish('user:login', false);
        //console.log(this.appService.loggedIn);
    }
```

The code in the tab component:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.events.subscribe('user:login', (user) => {
      // user here is actually indicating the true/false of logged-in status
      console.log('logged in as:', user[0]);

        this.loggedIn = user[0];
        console.log(this.loggedIn);

    });
  }
```